# Geração de build no projeto Maven

Tags: java, maven, release, integração-contínua

Gostaria de gerar uma build em Java utilizando Maven, onde o nome do arquivo gerado .jar fosse o mesmo número da última revisão do repositório SVN.

> Exemplo: A minha última build gerada possui a seguinte numeração:
>   1.0.0.51. E durante todo o mês de janeiro houve vários commits no repositório e agora desejo gerar uma nova build com a última revisão
>   do repositório, que no caso seria 1.0.0.201.

Como faço isso? Eu utilizo integração continua Jenkins e gostaria que os mesmos fossem integrados.

Realizei algumas pesquisas, mas não obtive sucesso. Existe algum plugin no maven que coloco no arquivo pom.xml que tem esse recurso?

Comment: O Jenkins já vem com integração com o maven no "pacote básico". Não é preciso alterar nada no pom.xml para configurar o Jenkins.

Comment: Pessoalmente, acho isso uma ma ideia, ja que ira quebrar o sistema de versionamento do maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem vários plugins para fazer o que você deseja.

Uma rápida busca no Google me retornou:

## [Build Number Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/)

Basta configurar o *plugin*:

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>create</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <doCheck>true</doCheck>
      <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Que vai alimentar a variável `buildNumber`.

```xml
<build>
   <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-r${buildNumber}</finalName>
</build>
```

## [Maven SVN Revision Number Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-svn-revision-number-plugin/)

Mesma coisa. Configuração de *plugin* + prefixo:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.code.maven-svn-revision-number-plugin</groupId>
   <artifactId>svn-revision-number-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.13</version> 
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <goals>
            <goal>revision</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
       <entries>
          <entry>
             <prefix>prefix</prefix>
          </entry>
       </entries>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

E o número de revisão estará disponível em `prefix.revision`

```xml
<build>
   <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-r${prefix.revision}</finalName>
</build>
```

---

Em ambos os casos vale a pena também configurar o [SCM](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/):

```xml
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://servidor/projeto/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://servidor/projeto/trunk</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
    <url>https://servidor/projeto/trunk</url>
</scm>
```

---

**Sugestão:** como você está tomando tempo para automatizar o processo, é recomendável [adicionar a versão do *build* ao Manifest](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/add-svn-revision-to-manifest.html). Colocando o *build number* no Manifest e armazenando um [checksum](http://nicoulaj.github.io/checksum-maven-plugin/) do artefato gerado você ganha confiança sobre a versão do *build* (apenas adicionar a versão ao nome do arquivo é bom para catalogação, porém não garante muita coisa uma vez que o artefato pode ser renomeado).

Comment: Anthony, foi mal! Li o nome do plugin errado.

Answer (score 3):

## A forma mais simples e "manual"

A prática mais simples para conseguir um artefato com a revisão do [VCS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_controle_de_vers%C3%A3o) no nome do arquivo é colocar a revisão desejada na versão configurada no `pom.xml`. Embora seja um procedimento "manual", isso ajuda a manter certa consistência.

O [Versions Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) pode ajudar um pouco nessa tarefa.

## Usando o plugin de *releases*

Existe ainda o [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) que poderia ser útil dependendo de como é o seu processo. Ele é capaz de criar um tag no SVN e atualizar a versão dos poms.

## Alterando o nome "final" do artefato no Maven

No Maven, você pode configurar a tag `<finalName>` no seu `pom.xml` para que, após o *build*, o artefato final tenha o nome que você quer. Veja a [documentação aqui](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element).

Por padrão, o maven adiciona a versão do pom, conforme a seguir:

```xml
<finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
```

Então você poderia definir uma outra propriedade qualquer, por exemplo:

```xml
<finalName>${artifactId}-${revisao_svn}</finalName>
```

E o Jenkins poderia ser configurado para passar o parâmetro `${revisao_svn}` para o Maven.

Se você usa um gancho (*hook*) como o [desta página](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin), então você terá o número da revisão numa propriedade.

Finalmente, bastaria configurar os parâmetros do *build* como explicado [neste link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build). Segundo [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510754/jenkins-how-do-i-use-the-parameterized-trigger-plugin-and-pass-a-subversion-rev) isso e perfeitamente possível.

---

**Nota**: atualmente eu não tenho um ambiente para testar tudo isso, então, a não ser que alguém dê uma solução mais detalhada, você terá que desvendar os detalhes do procedimento.