# Para que serve o Maven?

Tags: java, xml, maven, engenharia-de-software

Muitas vezes encontro projetos grandes que possuem o arquivo pom.xml, mas eu nunca entendi a utilidade do mesmo, apenas descobri que é alguma coisa relacionada com o maven. Enfim:

- Para que serve o Maven?
- Para que serve o arquivo pom.xml?

Comment: Havia me esquecido desse artigo: [Instalando, configurando e usando o Maven para gerenciar suas dependências e seus projetos Java](http://luizricardo.org/2014/06/instalando-configurando-e-usando-o-maven-para-gerenciar-suas-dependencias-e-seus-projetos-java/), ele é super completo e faz minha resposta mais parecer uma pequena introdução do assunto :)

Comment: Nossa, bem bacana mesmo. Vou ler agora, valeu (:

Comment: Nicolas, faço parte da comunidade Demoiselle que é um projeto de um framework em software livre brasileiro. Nossa comunidade oferece, através do SERPRO que é fundador, curso em formato ensino à distância no que chamamos de trilha-Demoiselle que abrange além do curso do próprio framework, os pré-requisitos para usar o Demoiselle. Um dos cursos é justamente sobre o apache-Maven: https://moodle.ead.serpro.gov.br/blocks/course_catalog/guia_aluno.php?exibe=c&org=2&categoria=2355&url  Caso tenha interesse nos contate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

O Maven é uma ferramenta desenvolvida pela Apache, ela serve para gerenciar as dependências e automatizar seus *builds*.

Já o `pom.xml` é o arquivo de configuração do Maven.

## Gerenciando as dependências

É muito comum encontrar projetos que fazem o uso de outras bibliotecas ou frameworks, para usá-los é necessário acessá-los através da dependências. As dependências em Java são arquivos comprimidos e armazenados com a extensão `.jar`. Alguns dessas dependências possuem uma ou mais subdependências e algumas delas possuem uma ou mais subsubdependências, e por aí vai. Ao invés de quando você precisar de uma dependência você ir em busca dela no Google, baixá-la, adicionar no seu projeto e descobrir que ela precisa de X novas subdependências e ficar num ciclo gigante à caça de dependências, você pode automatizar esse processo <strike>chato e</strike> cansativo, e focar no desenvolvimento que é o que realmente dá valor ao seu projeto.

O Maven automatiza isso para você!

Existe um repositório que é o considerado central do Maven que pode ser acessado através desse link: https://search.maven.org . Além dele existem muitos outros repositório espalhados por aí, e uma boa forma de encontrá-los é através do site http://mvnrepository.com/ que indexa outros repositórios e disponibiliza uma forma mais amigável de buscar as dependências que você necessita.

Ao pesquisar por uma dependência para ser acessada através do Maven você obterá um trecho XML que serve para configurar o `pom.xml` do seu projeto e indicar que você estará fazendo uso dessa dependência em seu projeto. Ao adicionar esse trecho, o Maven faz o download dela e armazena em um repositório local no seu computador, se você possuir mais de um projeto fazendo uso da mesma dependência você só terá um único arquivo no seu computador, no seu repositório local organizado pelo Maven.

Outra grande vantagem da dependência estar em um repositório local, e não na pasta do seu projeto, é que ao usar ferramentas de versionamento como por exemplo o GIT você não precisará adicionar os seus `.jar`s nele, já que a responsabilidade de gerenciar as dependências não é mais sua, mas sim do Maven.

Um exemplo de trecho XML que configura o Maven para usar uma dependência:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

## Automatizando os *builds*

Você pode automatizar tarefas do seu projeto que podem ser geração de arquivos `.jar`s executáveis fazendo uso apropriado das dependências ou até mesmo o *deploy* de aplicações *web*.

Por exemplo: [Geração de build no projeto Maven](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2317/3117) e [Criando JAR com dependências em Maven](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8218/3117)

Comment: Esse [http://mvnrepository.com/](http://mvnrepository.com/) nunca foi repositório central, ele só consulta em alguns repositórios, se você observar vê que o download disponível é um link para os externos. Para o central, olhe [http://central.maven.org](http://central.maven.org)

Comment: @brunocesar ops, vou consertar essa parte então, vou dar uma pesquisada para ver melhor como isso funciona, e talvez citar que outros repositórios tb podem ser adicionados no pom. Obrigado

Comment: Boa resposta, Math! Só vale notar que o @Bruno está certo. O mvnrepository.com é um indexador de repositórios, uma forma amigável de localizar dependências. Particularmente, eu acho ele mais rápido e amigável do que ver diretamente no repositório.

Comment: @utluiz boa resposta é a sua no seu blog, depois que eu me lembrei dela (lendo a sua resposta sobre deploy) deu vontade até de apagar a minha, rs.. Mas de qlq forma acho que aquele texto todo nem caberia aqui, então está aí meu resuminho. E vou consertar o que vcs observaram. Obrigado.